How to generate multiple text completions per prompt (like vLLM) using HuggingFace Transformers Pipeline without triggering an error?
I'm using the HuggingFace Transformers Pipeline library to generate multiple text completions for a given prompt. My goal is to utilize a model like GPT-2 to generate different possible completions like the defaults in vLLM. However, I am encountering an issue with unused model_kwargs when I attempt to specify parameters like max_length and num_return_sequences.
Here is the code snippet I'm using:
Copy code
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel, pipeline
from typing import List, Dict

def process_prompts(prompts: List[str], model: GPT2LMHeadModel, tokenizer: GPT2Tokenizer, num_completions: int = 3) -> List[List[str]]:
    device = 0 if model.device.type == 'cuda' else -1
    text_generator = pipeline("text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, device=device)
    outputs = []

    for prompt in prompts:
        try:
            results = text_generator(prompt, max_length=50, num_return_sequences=num_completions, num_beams=num_completions)
            completions = [result['generated_text'] for result in results]
            outputs.append(completions)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing prompt {prompt}: {str(e)}")

    return outputs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    model.to("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    example_prompts = ["Hello, how are you?"]
    processed_outputs = process_prompts(example_prompts, model, tokenizer, num_completions=3)
    for output in processed_outputs:
        print(output)

and also:
            results = text_generator(prompt, max_length=50, num_return_sequences=num_completions)

When I run this, I get the following error:
The following `model_kwargs` are not used by the model: ['max_len']
Note: I am aware that typos in the generate arguments can also trigger this warning, but I've checked and rechecked the arguments names.

and
   raise ValueError(
ValueError: Greedy methods without beam search do not support `num_return_sequences` different than 1 (got 4).

What could be causing this error, and how can I fix it to generate multiple completions effectively using the model?
cross: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-generate-multiple-text-completions-per-prompt-using-huggingface-transformers-pipeline-without-triggering-an-error/86297

I think this works:
# -- test

def pipeline_tests_():
    print(f'\n--> pipeline_tests_()')
    import torch
    from transformers import pipeline

    # pipe = pipeline(model="gpt2", device_map="auto", model_kwargs={"load_in_8bit": True})
    pipe = pipeline(model="gpt2", device_map="auto", model_kwargs={"load_in_4bit": True})

    output = pipe("This is a cool example!", do_sample=True, top_p=0.95, temperature=0.8, max_length=50)
    print(f'\n{output=}')
    print(f'{len(output)=}')

    output = pipe("This is a cool example!", do_sample=True, top_p=0.95, temperature=0.8, max_length=50, num_return_sequences=4)
    print(f'\n{output=}')
    print(f'{len(output)=}')

    output = pipe("This is a cool example!", do_sample=False, top_p=0.95, temperature=0.8, max_length=50, num_return_sequences=4, num_beams=5)
    print(f'\n{output=}')
    print(f'{len(output)=}')

    print()

# -- main 

def main(
        # path_2_eval_dataset: str = '~/gold-ai-olympiad/data/MATH/test',
        path_2_eval_dataset: str = '~/putnam-math/data/Putnam_MATH_original_static2/test',
        model: str = 'gpt-4-turbo',  # e.g., gpt-4-turbo, gpt-3.5-turbo
        start: int = 0, 
        end: int = sys.maxsize, 
        ):
    from evals.data_eval_utils import get_iter_for_eval_data_set
    from evals.prompts_evals import HELM_MATH_PROMPT_8SHOT_COT2_TEMPLATE, get_math_problem_prompt_ala_helm_8shot_cot2 
    # - Get eval data
    path_2_eval_dataset: Path = Path(path_2_eval_dataset).expanduser()
    math_gold_probs_solns: list[dict] = list(get_iter_for_eval_data_set(path_2_eval_dataset))
    math_gold_probs_solns: list[dict] = math_gold_probs_solns[start:end]
    print(f'{path_2_eval_dataset=} \n {len(math_gold_probs_solns)=}')
    assert len(math_gold_probs_solns) > 0, f'No math problems found in {path_2_eval_dataset=}'

    # - Get vllm generator
    prompt_template: str = HELM_MATH_PROMPT_8SHOT_COT2_TEMPLATE
    prompt_gen_func: Callable = get_math_problem_prompt_ala_helm_8shot_cot2
    math_prompts_problems: list[str] = [prompt_gen_func(gold_data_prob_soln, prompt_template) for gold_data_prob_soln in math_gold_probs_solns]
    math_guessed_outputs: list[str] = [f"Solution: Let's think step by step. " + gold_data_prob_soln['solution'] for gold_data_prob_soln in math_gold_probs_solns]

    # - Estimate cost of inference
    result = estimate_openai_api_inference_cost(prompts=math_prompts_problems, outputs=math_guessed_outputs, model=model, verbose=True)
    print(f'--> Inference cost: {result=}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import fire
    import time
    start = time.time()
    # main()
    # fire.Fire(main)
    fire.Fire(pipeline_tests_)
    # pyton boxed_acc_eval.py --model meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct
    print(f"Done!\a Time: {time.time()-start:.2f} sec, {(time.time()-start)/60:.2f} min, {(time.time()-start)/3600:.2f} hr\a")

output:
--> pipeline_tests_()
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/gold_ai_olympiad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py:1132: FutureWarning: `resume_download` is deprecated and will be removed in version 1.0.0. Downloads always resume when possible. If you want to force a new download, use `force_download=True`.
  warnings.warn(
The `load_in_4bit` and `load_in_8bit` arguments are deprecated and will be removed in the future versions. Please, pass a `BitsAndBytesConfig` object in `quantization_config` argument instead.
Truncation was not explicitly activated but `max_length` is provided a specific value, please use `truncation=True` to explicitly truncate examples to max length. Defaulting to 'longest_first' truncation strategy. If you encode pairs of sequences (GLUE-style) with the tokenizer you can select this strategy more precisely by providing a specific strategy to `truncation`.
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation.
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/gold_ai_olympiad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bitsandbytes/nn/modules.py:391: UserWarning: Input type into Linear4bit is torch.float16, but bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float32 (default). This will lead to slow inference or training speed.
  warnings.warn('Input type into Linear4bit is torch.float16, but bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float32 (default). This will lead to slow inference or training speed.')

output=[{'generated_text': "This is a cool example! I got my first two kids in my living room to play with, and I've played with them for years before that. It was so beautiful. They were so nervous.\n\nAdvertisement\n\nI don't think"}]
len(output)=1
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation.

output=[{'generated_text': 'This is a cool example!\n\nThe next thing I\'m going to do is create a class called "Misc.Libraries.Libraries.Libraries" and set it up with a simple definition:\n\n// This is a class'}, {'generated_text': "This is a cool example! In the video below, you can see how you can add a second time to your first time!\n\nIt's all about balancing the energy density of the atmosphere and the way you keep it going at night.\n"}, {'generated_text': "This is a cool example! I've tried to build a simple tool for tracking the change over time. My friends and I will try to improve it for everyone.\n\nFor now, I've started with a simple simple tool that takes just a"}, {'generated_text': 'This is a cool example!\n\nWe need to see how the system works.\n\nWe want to see how the "network" works.\n\nAnd what about "tasking" for an existing service.\n\nThis is just one'}]
len(output)=4
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/gold_ai_olympiad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/generation/configuration_utils.py:492: UserWarning: `do_sample` is set to `False`. However, `temperature` is set to `0.8` -- this flag is only used in sample-based generation modes. You should set `do_sample=True` or unset `temperature`.
  warnings.warn(
/lfs/ampere1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/gold_ai_olympiad/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/generation/configuration_utils.py:497: UserWarning: `do_sample` is set to `False`. However, `top_p` is set to `0.95` -- this flag is only used in sample-based generation modes. You should set `do_sample=True` or unset `top_p`.
  warnings.warn(
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation.

output=[{'generated_text': "This is a cool example!\n\nI've been working on this for a few months now, and I'm really excited to share it with you.\n\nI've been working on this for a few months now, and I'm really excited"}, {'generated_text': "This is a cool example!\n\nI've been working on this for a few months now, and I'm really excited to share it with you guys.\n\nI've been working on this for a few months now, and I'm really"}, {'generated_text': "This is a cool example!\n\nI've been working on this for a few months now, and I'm really excited to share it with you.\n\nI've been working on this for a while now, and I'm really excited to"}, {'generated_text': "This is a cool example!\n\nI've been working on this for a few months now, and I'm really excited to share it with you guys.\n\nI've been working on this for a couple months now, and I'm really"}]
len(output)=4

Done! Time: 33.57 sec, 0.56 min, 0.01 hr

ultimately this helped me https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/pipeline_tutorial#using-pipeline-on-large-models-with--accelerate-:
# pip install accelerate bitsandbytes
import torch
from transformers import pipeline

pipe = pipeline(model="facebook/opt-1.3b", device_map="auto", model_kwargs={"load_in_8bit": True})
output = pipe("This is a cool example!", do_sample=True, top_p=0.95)

and guessed the inputs names based on other attempts, errors.

error: 

error: Truncation was not explicitly activated butmax_lengthis provided a specific value, please usetruncation=Trueto explicitly truncate examples to max length. Defaulting to 'longest_first' truncation strategy. If you encode pairs of sequences (GLUE-style) with the tokenizer you can select this strategy more precisely by providing a specific strategy totruncation.

----

fix:

def pipeline_tests_():
print(f'\n--> pipeline_tests_()')
import torch
from transformers import pipeline
# pipe = pipeline(model="gpt2", device_map="auto", model_kwargs={"load_in_8bit": True})
pipe = pipeline(model="gpt2", device_map="auto", model_kwargs={"load_in_4bit": True})

# output = pipe("This is a cool example!", do_sample=True, top_p=0.95, temperature=0.8, max_length=50)
output = pipe("This is a cool example!", do_sample=True, top_p=0.95, temperature=0.8, max_length=50, truncation=True)
print(f'\n{output=}')
print(f'{len(output)=}')

output = pipe("This is a cool example!", do_sample=True, top_p=0.95, temperature=0.8, max_length=50, num_return_sequences=4, truncation=True)
print(f'\n{output=}')
print(f'{len(output)=}')

output = pipe("This is a cool example!", do_sample=False, top_p=0.95, temperature=0.8, max_length=50, num_return_sequences=4, num_beams=5, truncation=True)
print(f'\n{output=}')
print(f'{len(output)=}')

print()



error: Truncation was not explicitly activated butmax_lengthis provided a specific value, please usetruncation=Trueto explicitly truncate examples to max length. Defaulting to 'longest_first' truncation strategy. If you encode pairs of sequences (GLUE-style) with the tokenizer you can select this strategy more precisely by providing a specific strategy totruncation.

It seems to me that there are just a few minor issues in your code.

It's missing the import of torch.
There are some vars, depreciated that I changed.
Still, I get a few warnings, but I guess, it may not be important.

import torch
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel, pipeline
from typing import List, Dict


def process_prompts(prompts: List[str], model: GPT2LMHeadModel, tokenizer: GPT2Tokenizer, num_completions) -> List[List[str]]:
    device = 0 if model.device.type == 'cuda' else -1
    text_generator = pipeline("text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, device=device)
    outputs = []

    for prompt in prompts:
        try:
            results = text_generator(prompt, truncation=True,
                                     num_return_sequences=num_completions, num_beams=num_completions)
            completions = [result['generated_text'] for result in results]
            outputs.append(completions)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing prompt {prompt}: {str(e)}")

    return outputs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    model.to("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

    example_prompts = ["Hello, how are you?"]
    num_completions = 2
    processed_outputs = process_prompts(example_prompts, model, tokenizer, num_completions)

    res = ' '.join(processed_outputs[0])
    print(res)


Prints
Hello, how are you? How are you?"

"I'm fine," I said.

"Well, I guess I'm just fine," he said, turning to me.

"Well, I guess I'm just fine Hello, how are you? How are you?"

"I'm fine," I said.

"Well, I guess I'm just fine," he said, turning to me.

"Well, I guess I'm just not

